# Starting service on from browser in android

Tags: android, android-service

I want to start an service whenever a link is tapped in the browser i know from below intent filter we can start activity.

```
         <intent-filter> 
             <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

             <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
             <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" /> 

            <data android:scheme="acb" /> 

            android:host="*.abc.com"
             android:scheme="http" /> 
             <data
            android:host="*.abc.com"
            android:scheme="http" />
          </intent-filter>
```

Answer (score 1):

You would need to have the link start an activity which starts the service. You cannot directly start a service from a link.

Comment: the problem is when i start the new activity then the two instance off the app gets created one running in the background and one that i started.

Comment: @piyush: Normally, only one "instance off the app" will exist at a time. The only way this will change is if you do something unfortunate, like mess around with `android:process` attributes in the manifest.

Comment: what i want to say if my app is running in back ground and i click on the browser link,Then when i see the recent app list in the tablet i can see browser with my application thumbnail that is how two instance are created.

Comment: @piyush: There is one instance of the app, but it may have activities in two tasks. There are settings in the manifest that you can use to help control this, or you could simply `finish()` the activity after starting the service. Regardless, as I wrote in the answer, you cannot directly start a service from a link. So, either you use an activity that starts your service, or you get rid of your service, or you abandon this type of browser integration, or you stop writing the app.